# Perl6: Sub: restrict to static hash-return type

Tags: raku

I want to restrict the return type of some of my functions in Perl6.
I know, how to deduce the right return type of a function, returning a scalar  or an array in Perl6, but I don't know, how I can do this, if I use a hash of a particular type as return value?

Example: The Array approach can be seen in `test_arr()` and the Hash approach can be seen in `test_hash()`. So I want to specify the return value of `test_hash()`, to return a hash of class A.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use fatal;

class A { 
    has Str $.member;
}

sub test_arr() returns Array[A] {
    my A @ret;
    @ret.push(A.new(member=>'aaa'));
    return @ret;
}

sub test_hash() { #TODO: add `returns FANCY_TYPE`
    my A %ret;
    %ret.append("elem",A.new(member=>'aaa'));
    %ret.append("b",A.new(member=>'d'));
    return %ret;
}

sub MAIN() returns UInt:D {
    say test_arr().perl;
    say test_hash().perl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really the same as with arrays:

```
sub test_hash() returns Hash[A] {
    my A %ret;
    %ret.append("elem",A.new(member=>'aaa'));
    %ret.append("b",A.new(member=>'d'));
    return %ret;
}
```

Note that you can also write `%ret<elem> = A.new(...)`.

**Update**: For an hash of array of `A`, you need to do basically the same thing, you just need to be explicit about the types at every step:

```
sub test_hash() returns Hash[Array[A]] {
    my Array[A] %ret;
    %ret<elem> = Array[A].new(A.new(member => 'aaa'));
    return %ret;
}
```

But don't exaggerate it; Perl 6 isn't as strongly typed as Haskell, and trying to act as if it were won't make for a good coding experience.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But now I got anoter question: 
What about a Hash of Array of A?

sub test_hash_of_array() returns Hash[Array[A]] {
    my %ret;
    %ret.append("elem",[]);
    %ret{"elem"}.push(A.new(member=>'d'));
    return %ret;
}

Because this doesn't work.

Comment: @byteunit I've updated my answer to include an `Hash[Array[A]]` example, because it won't easily fit into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the example.